# Blocking call in parse's queryfortable

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nonblocking

I have an activity class, a theme class and a photo class. if there is a follow activity I need to find out what theme user follows, then what photos are tagged with that theme.
Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *themeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Occasion"];
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];

[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; 
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"followtheme"]; 
[followingActivitiesQuery includeKey:@"themePointer"];

NSArray *objects = [followingActivitiesQuery findObjects];

for (PFObject *object in objects) {
   PFObject *tobject = object[@"themePointer"];
   NSString *themename = [tobject valueForKey:@"name"];
   [themeQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo: themename];
}

PFQuery *photosFromFollowedThemeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[photosFromFollowedThemeQuery whereKey:@"themeRelation" matchesQuery:themeQuery];
```

This code works but the findobjects is a blocking call so my app hangs a bit while waiting. How do I rewrite this query ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `findObjects`, use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` which is executed asynchronously and does not block the main thread.

So your code would look something like this:

```
PFQuery *themeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Occasion"];
// ... add filters ...
[themeQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
}];
```

**[Update]** Here is some additional sample code for your query, I compiled this in my head so it might need some tweaking.

```
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; 
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"followtheme"]; 
[followingActivitiesQuery includeKey:@"themePointer"];
[followingActivitiesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    PFQuery *themeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Occasion"];
    for (PFObject *object in results) {
       PFObject *tobject = object[@"themePointer"];
       NSString *themename = [tobject valueForKey:@"name"];
       [themeQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo: themename];
    }

    PFQuery *photosFromFollowedThemeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [photosFromFollowedThemeQuery whereKey:@"themeRelation" matchesQuery:themeQuery];
    [photosFromFollowedThemeQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *finalResults, NSError *finalError) {
        // Do something with the final results
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Bjorn,  I am not doing themeQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. What I need is first to do [followingActivitiesQuery findObjects] to get all the theme pointers. Then I do another query on themeQuery. Then a 3rd query to get the photos.

Comment: I wasn't re-writing your complete query here, the focus should be on using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`. If you replace `findObjects` with it, you can construct the following queries in the callbacks and use the results of the previous queries in whatever way you need them for the following queries.

Comment: I  get that. the problem is I cant return photoQuery;  inside findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. any suggestion on how to construct the rest of the queries in the callback?

Comment: But I still need to return photosFromFollowedThemeQuery since I am using- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {